# DropWizard The following artifacts could not be resolved

Tags: dropwizard

This is my pom.xml file.. I am getting BUILD FAILED when i am using MAVEN compile

ERROR IS

Failed to execute goal on project com.wenable.login: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.wenable.aqua:com.wenable.login:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, io.dropwizard:dropwizard-assets:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, io.dropwizard:dropwizard-spdy:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, io.dropwizard:dropwizard-hibernate:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, io.dropwizard:dropwizard-migrations:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, io.dropwizard:dropwizard-views-freemarker:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, io.dropwizard:dropwizard-views-mustache:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.wenable.aqua
    com.wenable.login
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    LoginAPI

```
<properties>
    <dropwizard.version>0.7.0</dropwizard.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-auth</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-assets</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-spdy</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-migrations</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-views-freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-views-mustache</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <DependencyConvergence />
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.wenable.login.LoginApplication</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4):

All of your dropwizard dependencies are using `${project.version}` instead of `${dropwizard.version}`. Should look like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-auth</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-assets</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-spdy</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-migrations</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>
```